# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be of class $C^1$; write $f$ in the form $f(x, y_1, y_2)$. Assume that $f(3, -1, 2)=0$ and

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be of class $C^1$; write $f$ in the form $f(x, y_1, y_2)$. Assume that $f(3, -1, 2)=0$ and $Df=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 1\\  1& -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

(a) Show there is a function $g : B\to \mathbb{R}^2$ of class $C^1$ defined on an open set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x, g_1(x) , g_2(x)) = 0$ for $x\in B$, and $g(3) = (-1, 2)$.

(b) Find $Dg(3)$.

(c) Discuss the problem of solving the equation $f(x,y_1 , y_2) = 0$ for an
arbitrary pair of the unknowns in terms of the third, near the point
$(3, -1, 2)$.

This exercise, is already posted here [Application of Implicit Function theorem for this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851404/application-of-implicit-function-theorem-for-this-problem)  and here [Implicit Function Theorem computation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106263/implicit-function-theorem-computation-problem) but there is no answer for (c), I would like to know how to solve (c), could someone help me please?

Comment: How would you define "discuss" in the context of this question?

Comment: @David         
I define that as study or inquire

Comment: Could you try to be more specific? What precisely are you/the question trying to show?

Comment: @David What I want in (c), is to know if it is possible to clear the first two variables of $f$ in the second variable, is this possible? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you select the two columns in $Df$ you want to solve for in terms of the third variable. If the determinant is $0$, you are out of luck. Otherwise you can apply Implicit Function Theorem and repeat part $(a)$ and $(b)$